# How do I monitor and send alerts for status of a service running on an azure VM

Tags: azure, azure-monitoring

I want to develop a mechanism that will continuously send the status ( up or down ) of a custom service running on a VM. How do i do this ? Azure doesn't provide any direct solution.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. If you're running a custom service on your VM, it's up to you to decide how to make these stats / alerts available. There is no "right" way. As for Azure providing direct solutions: There are custom probes for VMs. Other than that, you'd have to choose how to publish and send alerts.

Comment: Well, i know it's up to me to decide how to make  the alerts but , I'm just starting out and have no idea how to do so and hence ,seeking out help

Answer (score 0):

Azure's Application Insights provides a way to do this. Within Application Insights, you have two options:

1. If your service has a public http endpoint, you can [set up a web test](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-monitor-web-app-availability) that will periodically ping the service to ensure it is up and running. You can then set an alert on the web test to get a notification if the ping returns a failure for a specified window of time.
2. If not, you can instrument your service using the Application Insights SDK (TrackMetric and TrackEvent API) and [set an Application Insights metric alert](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-alerts) on that custom/app metric.